# Ansible Task - Apply the condition for working office hours is getting skipped when I use single digit integer value

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, task

Please help me out to understand why my **Task** - Apply the condition for working office hours is getting skipped when I use single digit integer value and running fine when I use double digit integer value.

Below is my code in ansible:

- name: ansible date and time output
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: define ansible variable
  debug:
  var: ansible_date_time

  ```
      - name: Print msg variable
        debug:
                msg: "{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}"

      - name: Set variables
        set_fact:
                cur_time: "{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}"

      - name: Print Current time
        debug:
                msg:  "{{ cur_time }}"

      - name: Apply the condition for working office hours
        debug:
                msg: "Condition is successful"
        when:  cur_time >= "9" and cur_time <= "19"
  ```

In the last task if I use cur_time >="10" or "11" etc it works fine but when I use integer below 10 like "9" or "8" it fails.

Comment: have you tried setting a 0 infront of it ? Such as 09 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is not working as expected because you're performing String comparison to the `cur_time` variable.

To perform number comparison you first have to remove the `"` from the comparison, and this will return an error.

`'>=' not supported between instances of 'AnsibleUnsafeText'`.

Then have to convert the `cur_time` to an `int`. The final result would be.

```yaml
- name: "Test playbook"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
    - name: Print msg variable
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}"

    - name: Set variables
      set_fact:
        cur_time: "{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}"

    - name: Print Current time
      debug:
        msg:  "{{ cur_time }}"

    - name: Apply the condition for working office hours
      debug:
        msg: "Condition is successful"
      when:  cur_time | int >= 9 and cur_time | int <= 19
```

As a result the last task will be executed correctly.

```
TASK [Print Current time] ***************************************************
Wednesday 06 July 2022  12:44:42 +0200 (0:00:00.148)       0:00:03.885 ******** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "12"
}

TASK [Apply the condition for working office hours] ***************************************************
Wednesday 06 July 2022  12:44:42 +0200 (0:00:00.147)       0:00:04.033 ******** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Condition is successful"
}
```